# I'm confused in what to do to demonstrate downard concavity on an interval.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x) = -x^4 + 40x^3 - 400x^2 + 1000x$ which we know $f''(x) = -12x^2 + 240x - 800$. We have an interval $[0,4]$.

I know that if $f''(x) \leq 0 \ \forall x$ then $f(x)$ is downward concave. However it seems that I can't just compute $f''(0)$ and $f''(4)$ and call it a day. It seems tedious or down right impossible to compute the second derivative for every point in the interval. What should I do instead?

Comment: It would probably help if you shared the exact function $f(x)$ and $f''(x)$.

Comment: @sudeep5221 I updated the question.

Comment: Note that $f''(x)$ is a quadratic expression. Since the coefficient of $x^2$ is negative, $f''(x) > 0$ for between the roots of the quadratic and $f''(x) < 0$ otherwise. So compute the roots of the quadratic, you will find the regions where $f''(x) < 0$ and $f''(x) > 0$.

Comment: Is there a method where I could use the first derivative instead of the second to demonstrate concavity?

Comment: Solve $$-12x^2 + 240x - 800>0$$

Comment: It certainly would be downright impossible to compute the derivative for each point in the interval individually. However, as @sudeep5221 suggests, find the roots of the second derivative $f''(x)$. Note that the second derivative is a continuous function meaning that if the function were to change sign (from positive to negative or vice versa) it would have to pass through $0$, but since you'll know where the function is zero you can make statements like $f''$ is negative (or positive) on interval $[a,b]$ without checking all the points in $[a,b]$ individually.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-10)^2 = x^2 - 20 x + 100$$
$$-12(x-10)^2 = -12x^2 + 240 x - 1200$$

$$ 400-12(x-10)^2 = 400-12x^2 + 240 x - 1200 =-12x^2 + 240 x - 800 $$

You want to know when $ 400-12(x-10)^2 = 0,$ also when it is positive and when negative

If
$$ 400 = 12(x-10)^2 $$
then
$$\frac{400}{12} = \frac{100}{3} = (x-10)^2 $$
so that
$$ x-10 = \pm \frac{10}{\sqrt 3}  =  \pm \frac{10 \sqrt 3}{ 3}  $$
$$ x = 10  \pm \frac{10 \sqrt 3}{ 3}  $$

To find out about positive or negative, just check what you get for $x=10$ ,
that gives the sign in the middle interval. For outside, we know the larger root is below $20,$ the smaller root is above $0,$  so check at $x=20$ and at $x=0$